# Meaning of 'with'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositional-phrases

What is the meaning of 'with' in the below sentence? What relationship does it indicate?

> The story begins with the meeting of two businesswomen.

Answer (score 1):

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229612?rskey=NrHHps&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> *with* Definition 37(e)
>
> After *begin* or *end* and words of like sense, in various shades of
> meaning: indicating
>
> (a) that which constitutes the beginning or end, i.e. the initial or
> final part, element, stage, proceeding, etc. (after a personal subject
> and before a gerund now *by*, as in A. 37a(b)   above);
>
> (b) a person or thing acted upon or treated first or last (coinciding
> with 9);
>
> (c) (after *begin*, *originate*, etc.) the agent or source from which
> something takes its rise (allied to 11).

Without context, the above is the closest definition available in a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.